# Stored procedure to check data type of every value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I want to create a stored procedure that copy data from table A to table B. The structures of table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE table_A
(
    Name nvarchar(max) NULL,
    Id nvarchar(max) NULL,
    dob nvarchar(max) NULL,
    duration nvarchar(max) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE table_B
(
    Name nvarchar(2000) NULL,
    Id nvarchar(2000) NULL,
    dob datetime NULL,
    duration float NULL
)
```

I want to copy data from table A to table B but after checking each value of every column. For example I have to check that every dob of `table_A` is in `datetime` format or not. The values that are in `datetime` format should only be copied to table_B, and this has to be done for all columns respectively.

I have tried the following way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].tester
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @abc TABLE ([COLUMN_NAME] varchar(50), [DATA_TYPE] varchar(50));

    INSERT INTO @abc 
        SELECT 
            C.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME,
            TYPE_NAME(C.USER_TYPE_ID) AS DATA_TYPE
        FROM 
            SYS.COLUMNS C
        WHERE 
            C.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('table_A');

    DECLARE @xyz TABLE ([COLUMN_NAME] varchar(max), [DATA_TYPE] varchar(max));

    INSERT INTO @xyz
        SELECT 
            C.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME,
            TYPE_NAME(C.USER_TYPE_ID) AS DATA_TYPE
        FROM 
            SYS.COLUMNS C
        WHERE 
            C.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('table_B')

    INSERT INTO @pp1
        SELECT c.column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns c
        WHERE c.table_name IN ('table_A', 'table_B')
        GROUP BY c.column_name
        HAVING MIN(data_type) <> MAX(data_type)

    DECLARE @lst nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max);

    SELECT 
        @lst = STRING_AGG(column_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDE RBY column_name) 
    FROM @pp;

    SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO table_B (' + @lst + N') SELECT ' + @lst + N' FROM table_A';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

It's working but comparing the datatype of columns not for very value in the column.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. For example below query returns data which are not possible to convert to datetime

```
select *  
from table_A 
where try_convert(datetime,dob) is null
```